# AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'reshape' when loading a custom dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load a custom dataset to Tensorflow like this:

```
# Load the dataset
train_images = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  './data/',
  seed=123,
  image_size=(250, 250),
  batch_size=batch_size)

test_images = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  './data/',
  seed=123,
  image_size=(250, 250),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

This is my dataset structure:

```
data
    train
        a.jpg
        b.jpg
        c.jpg
    test
        1.jpg
        2.jpg
        3.jpg
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Found 13233 files belonging to 2 classes.
Found 13233 files belonging to 2 classes.
<BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 250, 250, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>
<BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 250, 250, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-4381d053064c> in <module>()
    144 
    145 # Add noise for condition input
--> 146 train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], raw_size, raw_size, channels)
    147 train_inputs = add_gaussian_noise(train_images, stdev=0.2, data_range=(0, 255)).astype('float32')
    148 train_inputs = normalise(train_inputs, (-1, 1), (0, 255))

AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

This is due to the fact that I am trying to process my dataset like this:

```
# Add noise for condition input
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], raw_size, raw_size, channels)
train_inputs = add_gaussian_noise(train_images, stdev=0.2, data_range=(0, 255)).astype('float32')
train_inputs = normalise(train_inputs, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
train_images = normalise(train_images, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
train_labels = train_images.astype('float32')

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_inputs, train_labels)).shuffle(buffer_size).batch(batch_size)

# Test set
test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], raw_size, raw_size, channels)
test_inputs = add_gaussian_noise(test_images, stdev=0.2, data_range=(0, 255)).astype('float32')
test_inputs = normalise(test_inputs, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
test_images = normalise(test_images, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
test_labels = test_images.astype('float32')
```

Where am I going wrong? I get that BatchDataset does not have a function `.reshape()` but how can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You have to use `tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape), `Dataset` doesn't contain a `reshape()` method.

```
train_images = tf.reshape(train_images, newShape)
```

Where `newShape` is a tuple containing your parameters.

Comment: Thanks but now I'm getting `AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'shape'` because of `train_images.shape[0]`

Comment: `Datasets` are not arrays (although they contain them). They don't have the same methods. [You have to use `tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape). Since you're using `tensor_from_slices()` there's really no reason to use `Dataset`, or you can just do all of the reshaping before you create the `Dataset`.

Comment: Your image folder structure is still incorrect. It should be `root_dir > classes > images`, not `root_dir > train/test > images`, [according to the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory).